# How to deploy dist and server side on Heroku correctly?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, deployment, pusher

I am creating a simple customer chat app for my school project using [Pusher](https://pusher.com/chatkit) according to their [tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/customer-service-chat-vue).

I want to deploy the app on Heroku so anyone can use this app and connect to it. This app has a client-side (Vue.js app) and a server-side (express) folder.

How can I make it work together by deploying it on Heroku or what have I do?

I have deployed the client-side on Heroku and the front-end works fine.

I also tried to deploy server-side, but it seems it does not communicate with each other.

The server works fine on the localhost, however, I need to make it work globally.

The code can be found in [this repository](https://github.com/ayoisaiah/vuejs-customer-support).
Server side settings are in *server.js*.

I have only changed some front-end stuff, but nothing important yet, so the code is pretty the same.

This is my first Vue.js & server deploying and I was trying several tips and tutorials, but none of them solved this issue.

Comment: a plus one for the GitHub repo, perfect to reproduce